# asp.net logic for fixing relative urls to full urls

Tags: asp.net, url, screen-scraping

i have a function that pulls URLs from various web resources. needless to say some are full valid URLS and some are relative as per the HTML of the page. below is my asp.net/ c# logic i derived for examining the URL and then generate a full usable URL from whats pulled from the site...

I have have not looked at this code in some time but i remember it was working well some months ago and now it needed many tweaks to get running - especially with relative paths and the regeneration of a FULL url from various relative variations.

is there a simpler way or method to accomplish this seemingly routing boilerplate task than what i have here?

NOTE:
origianlurl is the full url of the first searched page, and relativeUrl is a url found within the searched page (it can be a full www.site.com or a /contactus.html)

```
    private string ResolveRelativePaths(string relativeUrl, string originatingUrl)
    {
        if (relativeUrl.StartsWith("http") || relativeUrl.StartsWith("www"))
            return relativeUrl;

        if (relativeUrl.StartsWith("/"))
        {
            //get main url something.com
            Uri myURI = new Uri(originatingUrl);

            //add the relative page to the end
            return myURI.Host + relativeUrl;
        }

        string resolvedUrl = String.Empty;

        string[] relativeUrlArray = relativeUrl.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] originatingUrlElements = originatingUrl.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int indexOfFirstNonRelativePathElement = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= relativeUrlArray.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (relativeUrlArray[i] != "..")
            {
                indexOfFirstNonRelativePathElement = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        int countOfOriginatingUrlElementsToUse = originatingUrlElements.Length - indexOfFirstNonRelativePathElement - 1;
        //for (int i = 0; i <= countOfOriginatingUrlElementsToUse - 1; i++)
        for (int i = 0; i <= countOfOriginatingUrlElementsToUse ; i++)
        {
            if (originatingUrlElements[i] == "http:" || originatingUrlElements[i] == "https:")
                resolvedUrl += originatingUrlElements[i] + "//";
            else
                resolvedUrl += originatingUrlElements[i] + "/";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= relativeUrlArray.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i >= indexOfFirstNonRelativePathElement)
            {
                resolvedUrl += relativeUrlArray[i];

                if (i < relativeUrlArray.Length - 1)
                    resolvedUrl += "/";
            }
        }

        return resolvedUrl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Uri` class has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91.aspx) that you can use for that exactly. Given a base uri, which is your `originatingUrl` and a string (the relative part) it generates the full url. As far as I can see there is not a single thing in your method that cannot be done using the `Uri` class (maybe a few instances). My guess is that you could rewrite it to 5-10 LOC.

Comment: i use the uri class where i can but you never know what you will pull down from the web. since there are so many variables this custom code seemed to be a better fit for handling all the variations. i was afraid the uri class would toss errors left and right.

Comment: @kacalapy: You were afraid that it *would*? You didn't even try and automatically assumed that you could write better functionality than what is in the framework. The Uri class has a `TryCreate` method that returns false if it fails. That's not tossing errors left and right. I'm am 100% convinced that the `Uri` class is more robust and handles more special cases than your code.

Comment: i did try that's why i went the other way with this one... i am using uri calss at the top of the sample, can you detail use of the TryCreate i didnt seem to have this prior. also originally the code was .net 2.0 now i ported it all to .net 4.0